# Pandas Resample Missing Rows

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have a dataframe that I am resampling over a week period:

```
df = 

         Date Game_Mode  Count
0  2008-11-30         b      1
1  2009-07-03         b      1
2  2009-07-12         b      1
3  2009-07-18         b      1
4  2009-10-02         c      1
5  2009-10-21         a      1
6  2009-10-22         b      1
7  2010-01-29         b      1
8  2010-01-31         b      1
9  2010-02-28         a      1
10 2010-03-28         a      1
11 2010-04-16         a      1
12 2010-05-09         a      1
13 2010-07-07         a      1
14 2010-09-16         e      1
15 2010-10-26         e      1
16 2010-12-16         e      1
17 2010-12-22         e      1
18 2011-07-20         e      1
19 2011-08-23         e      1

df['Date'][0]
Timestamp('2008-11-30 00:00:00')
```

I resample on a week for the category `'a'` (I do this for all categories).

```
week = df[df['Game_Mode'] == 'a'].set_index('Date', drop=True).resample('1W-TUE').sum()['Count'].reset_index()
# wc.dropna(subset=['Count'], inplace=True)
week.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
week['Date_Week_{}'.format('a')] = week['Date']
week['Index_Col_{}'.format('a')] = week.index + 1
week.rename(columns={'Count':'Count_{}'.format('a')}, inplace=True)
```

Resampled week:

```
week

         Date  Count_a Date_Week_a  Index_Col_a
0  2009-10-27      1.0  2009-10-27            1
1  2009-11-03      NaN  2009-11-03            2
2  2009-11-10      NaN  2009-11-10            3
3  2009-11-17      NaN  2009-11-17            4
4  2009-11-24      NaN  2009-11-24            5
5  2009-12-01      NaN  2009-12-01            6
6  2009-12-08      NaN  2009-12-08            7
7  2009-12-15      NaN  2009-12-15            8
8  2009-12-22      NaN  2009-12-22            9
9  2009-12-29      NaN  2009-12-29           10
10 2010-01-05      NaN  2010-01-05           11
11 2010-01-12      NaN  2010-01-12           12
12 2010-01-19      NaN  2010-01-19           13
13 2010-01-26      NaN  2010-01-26           14
14 2010-02-02      NaN  2010-02-02           15
15 2010-02-09      NaN  2010-02-09           16
16 2010-02-16      NaN  2010-02-16           17
17 2010-02-23      NaN  2010-02-23           18
18 2010-03-02      1.0  2010-03-02           19
19 2010-03-09      NaN  2010-03-09           20
20 2010-03-16      NaN  2010-03-16           21
21 2010-03-23      NaN  2010-03-23           22
22 2010-03-30      1.0  2010-03-30           23
23 2010-04-06      NaN  2010-04-06           24
24 2010-04-13      NaN  2010-04-13           25
25 2010-04-20      1.0  2010-04-20           26
26 2010-04-27      NaN  2010-04-27           27
27 2010-05-04      NaN  2010-05-04           28
28 2010-05-11      1.0  2010-05-11           29
29 2010-05-18      NaN  2010-05-18           30
30 2010-05-25      NaN  2010-05-25           31
31 2010-06-01      NaN  2010-06-01           32
32 2010-06-08      NaN  2010-06-08           33
33 2010-06-15      NaN  2010-06-15           34
34 2010-06-22      NaN  2010-06-22           35
35 2010-06-29      NaN  2010-06-29           36
36 2010-07-06      NaN  2010-07-06           37
37 2010-07-13      1.0  2010-07-13           38
```

Here's my problem. I lose all the dates between `2009-10-27` to `2008-12-30` and from `2010-07-13` to `2011-08-23` to. How can I not lose these during the resample?

I'd like to end up with:

```
    week

         Date  Count_e Date_Week_e  Index_Col_e
   2008-12-02      NaN  2008-12-02            1
   2008-12-09      NaN  2008-12-09            2
          ...  # All weeks before 2009-10-27
          ...
          ... 
   2009-10-27      1.0  2009-10-27            X
   2009-11-03      NaN  2009-11-03            Y
          ...  
          ...
          ...
          # Standard resample in this period
   2010-07-06      NaN  2010-07-06           Z
   2010-07-13      1.0  2010-07-13           I
          ...
          ...
          ... # All weeks after 2010-07-13 up to:
   2011-08-23       NaN 2011-08-23           J
```

Comment: `a[a['Game_Mode'] == 'a']` the reason you should not use `a` and `b` for names. Or worse: reuse them...

Comment: @JHBonarius will rename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by

```
df[df['Game_Mode'] == 'a']
```

If you only select the df rows where `Game_Mode` is `a` (or one of he others), then you're throwing away the start and end dates.

What you could do is create an empty dataframe, which the same dates, but filled with NaNs. E.g.

```
import numpy as np
temp = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : df['Date'],'Game_Mode' : 'a', 'Count': np.nan})
```

Gives:

```
          Date Game_Mode  Count
0   2008-11-30         a    NaN
1   2009-07-03         a    NaN
2   2009-07-12         a    NaN
3   2009-07-18         a    NaN
4   2009-10-02         a    NaN
5   2009-10-21         a    NaN
6   2009-10-22         a    NaN
7   2010-01-29         a    NaN
8   2010-01-31         a    NaN
9   2010-02-28         a    NaN
10  2010-03-28         a    NaN
11  2010-04-16         a    NaN
12  2010-05-09         a    NaN
13  2010-07-07         a    NaN
14  2010-09-16         a    NaN
15  2010-10-26         a    NaN
16  2010-12-16         a    NaN
17  2010-12-22         a    NaN
18  2011-07-20         a    NaN
19  2011-08-23         a    NaN
```

And then update it with existing data (strangely enough this cannot be inlined):

```
temp.update(df[df['Game_Mode']=='a'])
```

Gives:

```
          Date Game_Mode  Count
0   2008-11-30         a    NaN
1   2009-07-03         a    NaN
2   2009-07-12         a    NaN
3   2009-07-18         a    NaN
4   2009-10-02         a    NaN
5   2009-10-21         a    1.0
6   2009-10-22         a    NaN
7   2010-01-29         a    NaN
8   2010-01-31         a    NaN
9   2010-02-28         a    1.0
10  2010-03-28         a    1.0
11  2010-04-16         a    1.0
12  2010-05-09         a    1.0
13  2010-07-07         a    1.0
14  2010-09-16         a    NaN
15  2010-10-26         a    NaN
16  2010-12-16         a    NaN
17  2010-12-22         a    NaN
18  2011-07-20         a    NaN
19  2011-08-23         a    NaN
```

If you then resample:

```
temp.set_index('Date').resample('1W-TUE').sum()['Count']
```

You get all your dates (`.sum()` doesn't return NaNs for me...):

```
Date
2008-12-02   0.0
2008-12-09   0.0
2008-12-16   0.0
2008-12-23   0.0
              ..
2011-08-02   0.0
2011-08-09   0.0
2011-08-16   0.0
2011-08-23   0.0
Freq: W-TUE, Name: Count, Length: 143, dtype: float64
```

Comment: This worked exactly as needed.Works on my real data too. Thanks JH, you've really helped me out.